# i want find near car in distance with geometry and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i want find near list of car from this point

i have repository interface and i am written this query

```
    @Query(value = "select * from Driver d where ST_DWithin(d.location, ?1, ?2 * 1000.0, false) = true", nativeQuery=true)
  List<Driver> findNearBy(Geometry geometry, Integer km);
```

but when run code i see this exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION driverservice.ST_DWithin does not exist
```

and this is service called the data base and this query :

```
public void test(Double lat,Double lon) {
    final Geometry geometry = wktToGeometry("POINT(" + lat.toString() + " " + lon.toString() + ")");
    if (!geometry.getGeometryType().equals("Point")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Geometry must be a point. Got a " + geometry.getGeometryType());
    }
    final Point newPoint = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(geometry.getCoordinate()));
    newPoint.setSRID(SRID);
    List<Driver> driver = driverRepository.findNearBy(newPoint,3);
    driver.forEach(x->{
        log.debug(x.toString());
    });

}
```

Comment: is your sql query working outside of the code?

Comment: many documented in sql used query like this but in spring boot i dont now

Comment: I would suggest try this in sql console first to make sure the query is correct

Comment: Could you share your solution?